# BrokenPipeError when finding learning rate/training using Fast.AI

Tags: python

I am practicing my machine learning skills by creating a CNN in Windows with Fast.AI/Pytorch. I have sucessfully created and initialized my dataset, but when I try training it or looking for the learning rate, I get a BrokenPipeError.

```py
...
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics = error_rate) #We're fine here

#Now either line of code will throw the same error.
learn.fit_one_cycle(1)
learn.lr_find()
...
```

This is the specific error I get.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-4d78bfcf8d69>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/.../Desktop/Homebrew AI/image_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../Desktop/Homebrew AI')

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Homebrew AI/image_test.py", line 36, in <module>
    learn.lr_find()

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\train.py", line 32, in lr_find
    learn.fit(epochs, start_lr, callbacks=[cb], wd=wd)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 200, in fit
    fit(epochs, self, metrics=self.metrics, callbacks=self.callbacks+callbacks)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_train.py", line 99, in fit
    for xb,yb in progress_bar(learn.data.train_dl, parent=pbar):

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastprogress\fastprogress.py", line 72, in __iter__
    for i,o in enumerate(self._gen):

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastai\basic_data.py", line 75, in __iter__
    for b in self.dl: yield self.proc_batch(b)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 193, in __iter__
    return _DataLoaderIter(self)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 469, in __init__
    w.start()

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 89, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I'm assuming that it has to do with Windows possibly? Any help into fixing this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, something funky happens with version 1.0.4 of PyTorch and Windows regarding multi-threading. Downgrading the version of PyTorch to 1.0.0 fixed the problem.